# How can I determine which pipe is the drain and which is the vent in rough plumbing?

Tags: basement, drain, pipe

My basement has the below slab drains pre-piped, but just capped off.  Coming up through the slab is a 4" cast iron pipe (toilet), (2) 2" pipes sink/vent and then a 10" or 12" square filled with stone for the tub or shower.

How do I tell which of the (2) 2" pipes is the sink drain vs the vent.  I assume this is vent for all of them.

Comment: A picture would be helpful. To see the layout of the pipes in the surrounding area will help decipher the purpose of each pipe. If there are no walls built anywhere, it will be even more difficult, even with pictures.

Comment: The square opening is likely going to have to have the pipe in it cut to length, and then add a trap to it and a shower drain installed at the proper height to make contact with the shower. The box will be filled in with concrete likely. A photo would be helpful as already mentioned.

Comment: It appeared as if you were asking two questions at once, so I edited out the second question. If you have more questions, feel free to ask them using the Ask Question button.